# Performing a delete statement with datetime in the where clause

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application I perform some insert in a table which has a datetime column. For creating the data to inserd in that column I use the following code:

```
Date d = new Date((new Date()).getTime()+60000);
String exDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ITALY).format(d);
```

and I have added this String in a DATETIME column (named timestamp) of my table.

Now I want perform a query in that table, which deletes all the rows in which the date in the timestamp column is greater then a givend Date. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE timestamp > mydate
```

I was trying to use the `delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)` method inside the `SQLiteDatabase` library.

Someone can help me?

Comment: why is this tagged mysql when you're using sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my experience, using a String as a date-time field is a bad choice. Use a `long` instead. Android can create/set `Date` or `Calendar` objects based on the Unix Epoch and comparing a `long` in the sqlLite is a breeze.

So yeah, my answer is: change the SQL create statement to use a INTEGER instead of TEXT and you can easilt call the delete statement you're trying to do.